# Show that (x+y)^3 is not equal to x^3+y^3 for some x and y in a field F

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

**Problem**

Let F be a finite field of characteristic 2 with more than two elements. Show that $(x+y)^3 \neq x^3+y^3$ for some $x,y \in F$

**Doubt**

If $2x=0$ for all $x \in F$ ,then

$(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3xxy+3yyx
=x^3+y^3+xxy+yyx$

Any suggestion or hint what to do after this .

Comment: Compare what you have to $x^3+y^3$, as the problem tells you to, and show that they aren't always equal.

Comment: @Arthur The problem is about understanding a specific field of characteristic $2$ and a specific example. Your hint is unhelpful.

Comment: @DavidHill Clearly, the simplification of $(x+y)^3$ cannot go any further, and it's time to start comparing the two expressions. The OP might not know that, as he seems stuck, and thus I point out what I think it's the best next step. Who are you to decide that that is unhelpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that
$$
x^3 + y^3 = (x + y)^3 \iff 0 = xy(x + y).
$$
So, you need to choose $x$ and $y$ such that both $x$ and $y$ are nonzero, and $x + y\neq 0.$ Can you show that you can always choose such elements in a characteristic two field $F\not\cong\Bbb F_2$? Hint: Start with $x = 1.$ What *can't* $y$ be?

Comment: Reading field for the first time . My concepts are little shaky on field extension. Will come back at your suggestion after reading a bit more.

Comment: @blueboy Try thinking about it like this. What goes wrong for a field with 2 elements? (Remember that the only such field is $\Bbb F_2 = \{0,1\}$.) Then think about how adding another element $\alpha\neq 0,1$ can fix the problem...

Comment: Any $\alpha \neq -1$ will do .right?

Comment: @blueboy Remember that $-1 = 1$ in a field of characteristic $2.$ And $\alpha$ better not be zero either!

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are going to have to consider a field extension. The polynomial $t^2+t+1\in\mathbb{F}_2[t]$ is irreducible. What equations can you try in $F=\mathbb{F}_2[t]/(t^2+t+1)$?

Comment: It looks like this question is about an arbitrary field of characteristic $2$ which is not $\Bbb F_2.$ Examining one specific field extension doesn't seem to be what the problem is after here.